# Installing natural language toolkit data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have problem with installing natural language toolkit for python 2.7. I have NLTK already installed and now i am trying to install necessary data.

I type into shell:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

NLTK downloader appears (TKinter window). I choose to download all packages and start downloading. Everything goes well. Until i get message "error with downlaoded zip file" and process stops.

I am using windows 7 and 64-bit python 2.7.

Please help

Comment: How many times have you tried?

Comment: I have triedd 2 times.

Comment: Did you try downloading "collections" --> "all"? That just worked for me on 64 bit Windows (8) python 2.7

Comment: Error appears when it's downloading framenet_v15.

Comment: Yes, i've tried "collections"--> "all"

Comment: When I try to extract framenet_v15 manually, i get following error:

!   C:\nltk_data\corpora\framenet_v15.zip: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged

Comment: @user2904150 , most probably the download was not complete.

Answer (score 1):

When I downloaded the NLTK data I had to run the downloader several times since it kept hanging.

Alternatively here is a list of the individual files: http://nltk.org/nltk_data/

You can grab framenet_v15 here:
http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/packages/corpora/framenet_v15.zip

Comment: http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/packages/corpora/framenet_v15.zip is removed and it redirect to nltk website itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have issues with the `nltk.download()` and it failed multiple times. So try installing nltk data from the command prompt.
Run the command `python -m nltk.downloader all`.